# displaying multiple inequality symbols using expression()

Tags: r

I have encountered difficulty trying to display multiple inequality symbols in a text box placed on a plot window in R. Using a single inequality is acceptable, such as `mtext(expression("a">="b"))`. However, using three inequalities, such as `mtext(expression("a">="b and c"<"d"<="e"))` leads to halting of execution by the interpreter, which complains that the second inequality symbol is unexpected. How can multiple inequalities be used within a single text box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do this by mixing `plotmath` symbol and `paste`:

```
mtext(expression(a>b ~and ~paste(c < d) <= e))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Both your answer and that of @SvenHohenstein were excellent. I chose to accept yours because `phantom()` appeared to add some extra whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `phantom()` for a non-visible symbol:

```
plot(1)
mtext(expression(a >= b ~ and ~ c < d ~ phantom() <= e))
```

[image]