# The title of the plot must include > and <=

Tags: r

I have a beautiful plot made in R and now only the title is missing.
 it should be :
    "z_p larger than 1.6 and smaller or equal 4" in math annotation

> expression() works fine if I have only one expression, but having something bracket between two mathematical annotation is not working.

I tried:

```
 title(main=expression(paste('1.6'<z[phot]<='4')))

 title(main=expression(1.6<z[phot]<=4))
```

but it does not work.
I can add the title in powerpoint, but the result is ugly and the file get too big. I would prefer to stick to R.

Any tip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
expression(paste(1.6 < z[phot]) <= 4)
```

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773853/displaying-multiple-inequality-symbols-using-expression) for this and other solutions.

Comment: @user7721228 If you consider my solution solved your problem, please accept the answer (the green check mark below the scoring arrows). Thanks! :)

Comment: ups! I was not aware of it. btw, it get green only after accepting.
Learned something also today...